# Random Tetris Shape

Tags: python, tetris

I am trying to write a python program that will draw a random Tetris shape onto a board. 
Here's my code:

```
def __init__(self, win):
    self.board = Board(win, self.BOARD_WIDTH, self.BOARD_HEIGHT)
    self.win = win
    self.delay = 1000 

    self.current_shape = self.create_new_shape()

    # Draw the current_shape oan the board 
    self.current_shape = Board.draw_shape(the_shape)

def create_new_shape(self):
    ''' Return value: type: Shape

        Create a random new shape that is centered
         at y = 0 and x = int(self.BOARD_WIDTH/2)
        return the shape
    '''

    y = 0
    x = int(self.BOARD_WIDTH/2)
    self.shapes = [O_shape,
                  T_shape,
                  L_shape,
                  J_shape,
                  Z_shape,
                  S_shape,
                  I_shape]

    the_shape = random.choice(self.shapes)
    return the_shape
```

My problem is in the "self.current_shape = Board.draw_shape(the_shape). It says the_shape is not defined but I thought I defined it in the create_new_shape.

Answer (score 5):

you did but the variable `the_shape` is local to the scope of that function. when you call `create_new_shape()` you store the result in a field, you should use it to reference the shape:

```
self.current_shape = self.create_new_shape()

# Draw the current_shape oan the board 
self.current_shape = Board.draw_shape(self.current_shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

`the_shape` is local to your `create_new_shape` function, the name falls out of scope once the function exits.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues.  The first is the scope issue that others have pointed out.  The other issue is that you never instantiate the shape, you return a reference to the class.  First, let's instantiate the shape:

```
y = 0
x = int(self.BOARD_WIDTH/2)
self.shapes = [O_shape,
              T_shape,
              L_shape,
              J_shape,
              Z_shape,
              S_shape,
              I_shape]

the_shape = random.choice(self.shapes)
return the_shape(Point(x, y))
```

Now the shape is instantiated, with the proper starting point.  Next, scope.

```
self.current_shape = self.create_new_shape()

# Draw the current_shape oan the board 
self.board.draw_shape(self.current_shape)
```

When you refer to pieces of data in the same object (here the board), you need to access them via self.*thing*.  So we want to access the board, and tell it the shape to draw.  We do so by *self.board*, then we add on the *draw_shape* method.  Lastly, we need to tell it what to draw.  *the_shape* is out of scope, it only exists in the *create_new_shape* method.  That method returns a shape though, which we assigned to *self.current_shape*.  So when you want to refer to that shape again anywhere inside the class, use *self.current_shape*.